# +1 to number held in string, through a function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a function (leaning on jQuery) that adds 1 to a number in a string, regardless of the number's value.

```
var addNumber = function(string) {

    var number = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" "));
    number = Number(number);
    number = number + 1;                            

    string = string + number + string.substring(string.indexOf(" ") + 1);

    return string;
}
```

If I had the following html:

```
<span class="one">1000</span>
<span class="two">4</span>
```

Why is the following js not swapping the values:

```
var one = $(".one"), two = $(".two");
addNumber(one.text()); // expected .one to now hold "1001".
addNumber(two.text()); // expected .two to now hold "5".
```

Thanks

Comment: Your function is not _setting_ any element content anywhere, it just returns a string value.

Comment: @CBroe I've adjusted my code so I'm setting `string`. Shouldn't this mean that `addNumber()` effectively sets `.one` and `.two` with the `return`?

Comment: @danMad This is, step by step, what your code currently does: 1. *Get the text value from a node* – 2. *Pass that value when calling function `addNumber()`* – 3. *`addNumber()` processes the value* – 4. *`addNumber()` returns the result*. What you're missing is to apply that return value in some way. In fact, you don't take care of it at all so it gets discarded right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because although your function returns the incremented number, you don't do anything with that value. You need to update the `text()` of `.one` and `.two` after calling your function.

Also note that your logic will have an issue when the number is in the middle of the string, or there are multiple numbers in a string. Regular expressions are a much better alternative to hacking around a string based on the position of the number. Try this:

```js
var addNumber = function(string) {
  return string.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
    return ++n;
  });
}

$('span').text(function(i, t) {
  return addNumber(t);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="one">1000</span>
<span class="two">4</span>
<span class="three">Multiple numbers 1092 in the 82 middle</span>
```

Also note that you could potentially make this in to a plugin so that the increment and the setting of the new value is done in a single call, although with logic this simple it's a little bit of overkill.

Comment: Just for my understanding, implicit coercion is essentially taking place in your `addNumber()` function, right?

Comment: That's correct. The `++` operator is coercing the type

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you just passing a string directly to the function `addNumber()` and not a object, therefor the function can not update the string of the element.

So either you can use @rory-mccrossan's solution, but you could also wrap it into a jQuery function for prettier code.

```js
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.addNumber = function() {
      var currentNumber = parseInt(this.text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10)
      currentNumber++;
      this.text(currentNumber);
      return this;
   }; 
})( jQuery );

//Example of usage, this will update add +1 to the element after 2 seconds.
setTimeout(function(){
 $('#one').addNumber();
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="one">1000</span>
```